# Convert dataframe back to nested list

Tags: r, yaml

I am tring to convert between YAML, list, and dataframe. I have a YAML that looks as follows:

```
sheet1:
  var1:
    type: character
    description: description for my var1
  var2:
    type: character
    description: description for my var2
sheet2:
  var3:
    type: character
    description: description for my var3
  var4:
    type: character
    description: description for my var4
```

I am reading it and converting to a dataframe using the following script:

```
library(yaml)
library(tidyverse)
yaml_file <- yaml::read_yaml("yaml.yaml")
mydf <- yaml_file %>% map(bind_rows) %>% bind_rows(.id = "sheet")
```

In some instances I would need to convert the dataframe back to my original YAML. Below is my unsuccessful current attempt.

```
a <- split(mydf, mydf$sheet)
b <- lapply(a, function(x) split(x, f = x[["var"]]))
c <- rapply(b, as.list, how = "list")
cat(as.yaml(c)) # Not the same as my input
```

Comment: You might not get back to the original since while binding the lists, you throw away the names

Comment: Minor comment: It's better not to mix `data.table` and `tidyverse` syntax; the `tidyverse` way would be `mydf <- yaml_file %>% map(bind_rows) %>% bind_rows(.id = "sheet")`.

Comment: @RonakShah, the dput is the following:
`list(sheet1 = list(var1 = list(type = "character", description = "description for my var1"), 
    var2 = list(type = "character", description = "description for my var2")), 
    sheet2 = list(var3 = list(type = "character", description = "description for my var3"), 
        var4 = list(type = "character", description = "description for my var4")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First as @Mauritus notes, lets either maintain `tidyverse` or only `data.table`.

Here is a way with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
yaml_file <- yaml::read_yaml("yaml.yaml")
mydf <- yaml_file %>% 
     map(bind_rows, .id='var') %>% 
     bind_rows(.id = "sheet")
mydf

# A tibble: 4 x 4
  sheet  var   type      description            
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>     <chr>                  
1 sheet1 var1  character description for my var1
2 sheet1 var2  character description for my var2
3 sheet2 var3  character description for my var3
4 sheet2 var4  character description for my var4
```

This ensures that there is no data lost. In your case, you loose the `var` part:
Now combining it back to `yaml` file:

```
 map(split(mydf[-1], mydf$sheet),~split(.x[-1], .x$var))%>%
     yaml::as.yaml()%>%
     cat()

sheet1:
  var1:
    type: character
    description: description for my var1
  var2:
    type: character
    description: description for my var2
sheet2:
  var3:
    type: character
    description: description for my var3
  var4:
    type: character
    description: description for my var4
```

Comment: Shorter : `yaml_file %>% map_df(~bind_rows(.x, .id = 'var'), .id = 'sheet')`